# Oracle Forms 11gR2: FRM-10039: Unable to start up the Form Builder

Tags: linux, forms, oracle, suse, motif

Oracle Forms & Reports 11gR2 on SUSE SLES 11 here.

I successfully installed the software but when I launch the forms builder command:

$ $ORACLE_HOME/bin/frmbld

I get the message:

"FRM-10039: Unable to start up the Form Builder".

ORACLE_HOME is set
FORMS_BUILDER_CLASSPATH is set
I tried to unset LANG and NLS_LANG but the error is still there

It seems not to be a motif/Xwindow problem because the form compiler command shows a graphic interface:

$ $ORACLE_HOME/bin/frmcmp

Any suggestion?

Thank you, Cristian

Answer (score 1):

on Fedora I have to run the $ORACLE_HOME/asinst_1/bin/frmbld.sh

check if a shell script exists - ran into similar problem trying to execute a binary instead of the shell script.